# How to use different database depending on file location

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how exactly should I do this. But general idea is that when someone access our script on:
- http://livescript.phpiscool.com OR any of the sub folders

The database should be normal "live" database.

But when someone is trying to enter/navigate:
- http://livescript.phpiscool.com/beta1
OR
- http://livescript.phpiscool.com/beta2

The script should use different database ("beta" database)...

We have databse configuration in config.php and it looks like that:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "tureh_user";
$db_password = "crazypssrd";
$db_name = "database_test";
?>
```

Comment: Would have to know more about your build process most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will contain everything from the first slash after the domain onwards, so checking for it starting at position 0 with '/beta' should do the job

```
if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'/beta') === 0)
{
  $db_host = "beta";
}
else
{
  $db_host = "localhost";
}
```

the explicit comparison (===) means a int of 0 rather than (==) which may give a false positive on "false" if it fails to find a match

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, that kind of problem is handled by a configuration array:

```
$db['live'] = array(); // Your live configuration
$db['beta'] = array(); // Your beta configuration

$mode = process_url_to_get_mode();
```

Then, make use of `$db[$mode]` to instantiate your connection.
That's actually how CodeIgniter [does it](http://codeigniter.fr/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

Of course, you can rely on a function like Scuzzy gave you to get `$mode`.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to maintain two copies of your code base, one for the beta and one for the live version. This is trivial if you are using source control such as subversion, which uses a concept similar to folders called "branches" (wikipedia article on Subversion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion ). The benefits of having two copies of you code for beta and live are;

- If you make a change to the BETA edition of the site during development which accidentally breaks the site, the live site won't be affected.
- As your site grows, you can move the BETA or development copy onto a different machine, or your local machine for development at some point.
- You don't litter your code with nasty checks, to see if you are running development/live edition.

If you are using the Apache webserver, you can host these two separate sites to run at the same time using Apache VHosts (assuming you control the server yourself); http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

In the long term, it is the better solution.